# MVC 3 remote validation for multiple fields

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, remote-validation

I would like to validate that at least one of three fields is not empty. I am trying to do this using ASP.NET remote validation mechanism.

I have the following model:

```
public class MyModel
    {
        public MyModel()
        {
            EmployeeIds = new List<int>();
            ManagerIds= new List<int>();
        }

        [Remote("AtLeastOneSelected", "Company", AdditionalFields = "EmployeeIds, ManagerIds")]
        public int? SuperManagerId { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<int> EmployeeIds { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<int> ManagerIds{ get; set; }

    }
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult AtLeastOneSelected(int supermanagerid, IEnumerable<int> employeeids, IEnumerable<int> managerids)
        {
            var isSuperManagerSelected = Request.Params["SuperManagerId"] != "null";
            var isEmployeeSelected = Request.Params["EmployeeIds"] != "null";
            var isManagerSelected = Request.Params["ManagerIds"] != "null";
            return Json(isSuperManagerSelected || isEmployeeSelected || isManagerSelected, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

EmployeeIds and ManagerIds are implemented on the view using multiselect.
It was validated once when I modified SuperManagerId first time. And when I try to modify it again or even submit my form, remote validation doesn't work.

I tried to force validation on the view:

```
$('body').on('click', '#create-company', function () {
    $("form").validate().form();
    if ($("form").valid()) {
        alert('valid');
        $("form").submit();
    } else {
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

but it didn't help.

Comment: Is the remote validation request even being made? Install fiddler (http://fiddler2.com) and check if the request for validation is sent...

Comment: Checked. The request is sent only once(after the first editing). And there are no errors in browser console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. 
The result of the first validation was cached. Attribute `[OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]` helped.